# How to remove sidebar permanently samsung note 2

Tags: android, sidebar, samsung-mobile

I want to remove side bar from samsung note 2(GT-N7100).long press on back button hide and shows the side bar.If i disabled it and rebooted device it shows again on screen. I want to remove sidebar permanently from phone.
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible without modding your ROM, i guess you are using the Stock ROM. You could look trough [here](http://galaxynote2root.com/best-note-2-roms/) to find a ROM that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Note 2 (4.1.2) with a stock ROM and to permanently remove the sidebar I have to disable the "Multi window" option that is located in the notification bar if you swipe down from the home. Please notice you have to scroll the list to the right to get that option.

[image: Multi window option]